# Java: Multi Key/Value Map

Tags: java, collections

I'd like to have a Java collection that is like a Map but with multiple keys and multiple values.

**Sample:**

Lets say we have 3 keys and then 3 values for an element.

```
set (key ("G", "Merc", "SUV"), val ("silver", "400", "100.000"));

val v = get (key ("A4", "Audi", "Sedan"))
```

Does such a collection exist in some library?

Comment: have a list as key and value. Possible?

Comment: It does not. You either make your own, or use custom objects to contain multiple values, then use those as keys/values

Comment: you mean something like HashMap< Set<String>, Set<String>> ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, and the way I'd recommend, is to simply create 2 java classes, one will be key, the other will be the value.

```java
class Key {
    String str1, str2, str3;
}

class Value {
    String str1, str2, str3;
}

// later on

Map<Key, Value> map = ...;
map.put(new Key("G", "Merc", "SUV"), new Value("Silver", "400", "100.000"));
map.get(new Key("A4", "Audi", "Sedan"));
```

Of course, this isn't the only way, but it's the most easily maintainable, and also easiest to modify later on, if say you want to add another property to your keys.

Other ways include using `String[]` as the key and values, `List<String>`, and/or `Set<String>`. You might even roll your own implementation of `Map<T>`, but again, maintainability is a factor you must consider.

Comment: Just remember that this will not work at all unless you override `hashCode` and `equals`

Answer (score 1):

If I were going to do this I would just "glue" the keys together with some delimiter and make the key a single string.

```java
Map<String,Value> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(key("G", "Merc", "SUV"), new Value("Silver", "400", "100.000"));
map.get(key("A4", "Audi", "Sedan"));

public static String key(String...elements) {
    return String.join("-", elements);
}
```

Comment: In this case better not use dash as delimiter since it is quite common. But I think one gets the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Or do a combination of the already suggested answers.

Use a custom class as key and a `MultiValueMap` for the values.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html